# Перебор свойств объекта без метода

Tags: javascript

Есть объект с методом, нужно вывести все его свойства, но без метода.

```
for (let k in ivan) {
  if (!ivan.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
    console.log(k)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let ivan = {
  p: 123,
  m1: function() {},
  m2: () => {}
};

for (let k in ivan) {
  if (typeof ivan[k] != 'function') 
    console.log(k, typeof ivan[k]);
}
```